# apps wanting setting control

Tags: permissions

I am new to Galaxy S3 abd am trying to download apps. With each one I get the list of settings the app wishes to share/link. With the i-phone there is the yes/no option of allowing this control, but I am not able to do this with the S3. I do not particulary want the app to share/control me details etc.
Is there another way of downloading apps?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not clear. In my understanding, you are talking about the App Permissions.

So you when you are installing an app, it will say what information that particular app will get from your mobile. That is the nature of a privacy agreement. If you like it and say yes, it will be downloaded and install. If you don't want then you can be without installing it. No big deal.

But if you want the app and don't want to reveal yourself to it, then there is no way. Almost all the apps are mainly targeting the users for a customized use. So somehow you have to accept yourself to have that feature.

I wonder why you are worried much. If you don't like, just be not using it.

> PS: OR you can simply download an app and turn off the data so it won't
>   send much information to others till you connect to internet to
>   download another app